# "No runtime environment deployed in this server" on MobileFirst Platform server 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have deployed the `worklight` runtime project .war file.

the following error I am getting in the system log

> Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.

Comment: mobilefirst version? are you doing this in the studio version? what jvm are you using?

Comment: MobileFirst Platform server 7.1 on AIX, using jvm 1.7

Comment: Provide your messages.log file. Upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Without the messages.log file that will most likely pinpoint the issue here, my guess is that you improperly deployed your project's .war file to the application server.

You need to ensure to have followed the instructions provided [in this user documentation topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html) and that you've used the Configuration Tool to deploy the .war file. The tool also configures the server.xml file for you, where the .war file is typically defined.